# Apache HTTP Client forcing UTF-8 encoding

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, utf-16

I'm making a rest call using the `org.apache.http` package as below. I'm expecting user profile details in the response in English and other international languages.

```
HttpGet req = new HttpGet(baseUrl + uri);
HttpResponse  res= closeableHttpClient.execute(req);
```

The response has UTF-8 as character set, which is what I wanted. From here, I used 2 approaches to unmarshall the response to a map.

Approach-1:

```
String response = EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity(),"UTF-8");
// String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(),Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
map = jsonConversionUtil.convertStringtoMap(response);
```

Issue:

`httpResponse.getEntity()` was returning `StringEntity` object which had default charset as ISO_8859_1, but even when I force to convert to UTF-8 (uncommmented line and commented line above, both I tried), I'm not able to override to UTF-8.

Approach-2:

```
HttpEntity responseEntity = res.getEntity();
 
if (responseEntity != null ) {
    InputStream contentStream = responseEntity.getContent();
    if (contentStream != null) {
        String  response = IOUtils.toString(contentStream, "UTF-8");
        map = jsonConversionUtil.convertStringtoMap(response);
    }
}
```

Issue:

`IOUtils.toString(contentStream, "UTF-8");` is not setting to UT8.

I am using httpclient 4.3.2 jar & httpcore-4.3.1 jar. Java version used in Java 6. I can't upgrade to a higher java version.

Can you please guide how I can set to UTF-8 format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `StringEntity` object has an ISO-8859-1 encoding, then the server has returned its response encoded as ISO-8859-1. Your assumption that *"the response has UTF-8 as character set"* is most likely wrong.

Since it's ISO-8859-1, both your approaches don't work:

- **Approach 1**: The `"UTF-8"` parameter has no effect as the parameter specifies the default encoding in case the server doesn't specify one (see [EntityUtils.toString()](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString(org.apache.http.HttpEntity,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)). But the server has obviously specified one.
- **Approach 2**: Reading the binary content as UTF-8, which is in fact encoded in ISO-8859-1, will likely result in garbage (though many characters have a similar representation in UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1).

So try to ask the server to return UTF-8:

```
HttpGet req = new HttpGet(baseUrl + uri);
req.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.addHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
HttpResponse  res = closeableHttpClient.execute(req);
```

If it disregards the specified characters set and still returns JSON in ISO-8859-1, then it will be unable to use characters outside the ISO-8859-1 range (unless it uses escaping within JSON).